# Add user to WildFly via Maven

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

1. I create a maven project
2. Declares WildFly as a dependence in the area
3. Declares a `wildfly-maven-plugin` as a dependency in the space
4. I run `mvn wildfly: start`
5. I start localhost: 9990
6. I see a message that I have to add a user

Question

How to add this user? in WildFly with no Maven it is natural to enter `wildfly/bin` and run `add-user.sh` but how to do it well in Maven project, finally I go do `target/wildfly-run/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/bin/add-user.sh` but I'm guessing that this should not be good..

Answer (score 3):

In `pom.xml`

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <add-user>
                        <users>
                            <user>
                                <username>admin</username>
                                <password>admin.1234</password>
                            </user>
                            <user>
                                <username>admin-user</username>
                                <password>user.1234</password>
                                <groups>
                                    <group>admin</group>
                                    <group>user</group>
                                </groups>
                                <application-user>true</application-user>
                            </user>
                            <user>
                                <username>default-user</username>
                                <password>user.1234</password>
                                <groups>
                                    <group>user</group>
                                </groups>
                                <application-user>true</application-user>
                            </user>
                        </users>
                    </add-user>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```

Source: Section **Add a user before running the server** of

https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/run-example.html

Comment: its realy strange becouse i see in console `Adding users: User{username=admin-user2, groups=[admin, user], realm=null, applicationUser=true} but when i went to localhost:9990 i still see the same view that i need to add user, but when i do what i did before it works..

Comment: Do you have a user set with `<application-user>false</application-user>`? Or at least that configuration option left off.